# nginx: set custom header in location directive

Tags: nginx

I'd like to set a custom "X-Cache-Status" header when the **first file** in `try_files` is found, but not when any of the others match. What's the best approach to do that?

```
server {
    location / {
        try_files /cache/${host}${cache_uri}_index.html $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative answer, without if :

```
server {

    location / {
        add_header X-Cache-Status "foo";
        try_files /cache/${host}${cache_uri}_index.html @fallback;
    }

    location @fallback {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have no other choice then just to partially duplicate try_files functionality:

```
server {
    location / {
        if ( -f "$document_root/cache/${host}${cache_uri}_index.html" ) {
                add_header X-Cache-Status "value";
                break;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: `add_header` inside if will give unexpected results - see IfIsEvil